# Why can't I have a "desired password" field on a Cognito Form?

Tags: cognito-forms, terms-of-service

I added a field on my form to ask the customer for their desired password (the form is to register for our online access). I received an error that I may be violating the terms of service with this field. Am I not allowed to ask for passwords?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to bad people using [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) to conduct phishing attacks, we automatically block forms that collect certain types of information like passwords (I have to be a bit vague here on purpose).  However, there are two ways you can bypass this to collect passwords:

1. [Submit a support request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support) and ask us to review your form
2. Upgrade to a [paid plan](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing)

Furthermore, I recommend using our [data encryption](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/data-encryption) feature to protect passwords, as people frequently use the same password for multiple accounts and this type of information should be protected as much as possible.